# Launch any application on emulator via terminal

Tags: android, command-line

How do I launch any application via a terminal or command shell on android emulator engine? For example, if I want to start any game, how do I do via a terminal or command shell?

Anyone could help is really appreciated.

Thanks,

Sam.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `am start` command trough adb.
Example for the browser app floating around the internet:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity
```

Comment: Thanks Nanne for the follow up. But how can we do this for a game let say a monkeyjump.apk? How can we get parameters for these "-a" and "-n" switches?

Comment: You need Window prompt> **adb shell am start** and then the rest